# Is it possible to pause a command running under screen?

Tags: unix

I'm running a long executing command (currently on day 7) under screen. I would like to temporarily suspend this command to perform some other computationally expensive operation and then resume the screened command afterwards.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK. I figured it out.

**To Pause:**

- `screen -r` attaches to the screened command:
- `CTRL+z` suspends the process.
- `CTRL+A d` detaches from the screened command. (Do **not** exit.)

**To Resume:**

- `screen -r` attaches to the paused screen.
- `fg` continues the previously suspended command.
- `CTRL+A d` detaches from the screened command, leaving it running in the background.